# Replicate data with minimal downtime using transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have a SQL Server database with nearly 7TB of data. I want to replicate it using transaction replication.

What will be its approximate downtime? Please suggest a method to implement it with minimal or zero down time if any?

We have not yet implemented the procedure so I don't know exactly about the latency. We are planning to do it with normal LAN (in GB).

Comment: approximate downtime of what ? during which phase of transactional replication you expect a downtime ? another question is what SQL Server version and Edition you use ?

Comment: Latency will depend much on the amount of changes made to replicated objects as well as overall activity and resource utilization on the source and target.